# validate asp button on submit at client side in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I was trying to find a way to call a javascript function and a button onclick event from single asp button click and i did here is the code :

**My Button**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="checkDate()"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></aspButton>
```

**Javascript code**

```
function checkDate() {

        var startDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPeriodFrom.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;
        var toDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPriodTo.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;

        if (new Date(startDate).getTime() > new Date(toDate).getTime()) {

            alert("To date must be greater than from date.!!");
        }
}
```

Here this javascript working fyn, but I want to call the `OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"` if the javascript return true only. If the toDate less than startDate, it should not call the `OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"`.

Thanks All in Advance

Comment: use OnClientClick="return checkDate()"  instead OnClientClick="checkDate()" and make sure checkDate return always true/false from code (which is not currently done in code)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery click event inside `doucment.ready()`:

```
$(function(){

  $('#'+'<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').click(function(){

     var startDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPeriodFrom.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;
     var toDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPriodTo.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;

     if (new Date(startDate).getTime() > new Date(toDate).getTime()) {

        alert("To date must be greater than from date.!!");

        return false; // note this statmement will stop to call server event of click
      }

  });


});
```

Your button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" 
            name="btnSubmit" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" 
            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Button:**

```
OnClientClick="checkDate(this); return false;" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
```

Description:

```
checkDate(this);
```

Call's your function and pass the the button-object (this).

```
return false;
```

prevents PostBack.

**JavaScript:**

```
function checkDate(btn) {
 var valid = false;
 //your Code, set valid = true; if date is correct.
 if(valid){
   __doPostBack(btn.name,"");
 }
}
```

Description:

```
//your Code
```

stand for your validation code.

```
if(valid){
       __doPostBack(btn.name,"");
}
```

'valid' is a variable where you save the result of your validation.

__doPostBack(btn.name, "") call's a PostBack on the control you pass in the first parameter (need's the UniqueID therefore 'btn.name')

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining to the user what went wrong.

Comment: @theMayer adapted response :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all

This code is working fyn

```js
function checkDate() {

        var startDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPeriodFrom.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;
        var toDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPriodTo.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;

        if (new Date(startDate).getTime() > new Date(toDate).getTime()) {

            alert("To date must be greater than from date.!!");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return checkDate();" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
```

asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return checkToDate();" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"

Answer (score -1):

HTML code :

```
OnClientClick="return checkDate();"
```

Javascript code:

```
function checkDate() {

        var startDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPeriodFrom.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;
        var toDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPriodTo.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;

        if (new Date(startDate).getTime() > new Date(toDate).getTime()) {

            alert("To date must be greater than from date.!!");
            return true;

        }
else
{
return false;
}

}
```

Comment: code is wrong and also submit button will post automatically rather manually clicking , not correct approach

Comment: @vishalsharma you can delete it i can't

Comment: function checkDate() {

        var startDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPeriodFrom.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;
        var toDate = document.getElementById('<%=dtPriodTo.Controls[0].ClientID%>').value;

        if (new Date(startDate).getTime() > new Date(toDate).getTime()) {

            alert("To date must be greater than from date.!!");
        }
        else
            //__doPostBack("btnSubmit_Click", "");
            //document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').click()
            document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit%>').click();
    }

Comment: @Fasal if `function checkDate` returns true it will postback and it will fire `btnSubmit_Click` on server side... did you use `OnClientClick="return checkDate();"` this

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this inside `if`

```
document.getElementById('<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
```

OR

```
$('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').click();
```

OR

```
$("#btnSubmit").click();
```